# Simple bash program which compares values

Tags: bash, shell

I have a file which contains varoius data (date,time,speed, distance from the front, distance from the back), the file looks like this, just with more rows:

```
2003.09.23.,05:05:21:64,134,177,101
2009.03.10.,17:46:17:81,57,102,57
2018.01.05.,00:30:37:04,354,145,156
2011.07.11.,23:21:53:43,310,125,47
2011.06.26.,07:42:10:30,383,180,171
```

I'm trying to write a simple Bash program, which tells the dates and times when the 'distance from the front' is less than the provided parameter ($1)
So far I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -eq 0 -o $# -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "wrong number of parameters"
fi
i=0
fdistance=()
input='auto.txt'
while IFS= read -r line
do
    year=${line::4}
    month=${line:5:2}
    day=${line:8:2}
    hour=${line:12:2}
    min=${line:15:2}
    sec=${line:18:2}
    hthsec=${line:21:2}
    fdistance=$(cut -d, -f 4)
    if [ "$fdistance[$i]" -lt "$1" ]
    then
        echo "$year[$i]:$month[$i]:$day[$i],$hour[$i]:$min[$i]:$sec[$i]:$hthsec[$i]"
    fi
    i=`expr $i + 1`
done < "$input"
```

but this gives the error "whole expression required" and doesn't work at all.

Comment: please update the question with the `random error` you received; also consider cutting-n-pasting your code into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended code changes

Comment: Those `[$i]`s look like you're treating your variables as arrays, but they're not arrays (and that's not the right syntax if they were). Also, what is the input to `cut`? Also, instead of all the fixed-width field splitting stuff, I'd use something like `IFS=, read date time speed fdistance bdistance` (and then split those fields with e.g. `IFS=. read year month day <<<"$date"`) -- see [BashFAQ #1: How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Comment: Bash and `sh` are not the same shell, which one do you actually use? How do you run your code?

Comment: you've stated the first (comma delimited) field of input looks like:`-2003.09.23.` ... why does the year have a leading minus sign, and why the trailing period? I'd suggest updating the question with the first 5-10 lines from your file (`auto.txt` ?)

Comment: consider cutting-n-pasting your code into [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the recommended code changes; afterwards if you're still having issues please update the question with the latest copy of your code as well as an update on the issue(s) you're running into

Comment: Never use `-o`; it's obsolete and there are always better alternatives, especially when using `bash`.

Comment: `[ $# -eq 0 -o $# -gt 1 ]` .... why don't you simply say `[ $# -ne 1 ]`, or, more idiomatic, `(( $# != 1 ))`?

Comment: You define `fdistance` as (empty) array, but later on use it as if it were a scalar.

Answer (score 1):

Would you try the following:

```
#/bin/bash

if (( $# != 1 )); then
    echo "usage: $0 max_distance_from_the_front" >& 2           # output error message to the stderr
    exit 1
fi

input="auto.txt"

while IFS=, read -r mydate mytime speed fdist bdist; do         # split csv and assign variables
    mydate=${mydate%.}; mydate=${mydate//./:}                   # reformat the date string
    if (( fdist < $1 )); then                                   # if the front disatce is less than $1
        echo "$mydate,$mytime"                                  # then print the date and time
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Sample output with the same parameter as Keldorn:

```
$ ./test.sh 130
2009:03:10,17:46:17:81
2011:07:11,23:21:53:43
```

Comment: why use `tr` when you have `${mydate//./:}`?

Comment: You can then drop the last `':'` with `${mydate:0: -1}` (the space before `-1` is required, or you can put the negative offset in parenthesis, e.g. `(-1)`). Or, as you have done, starting with `${mydate%.}` is fine to trim the last `'.'`

Comment: Thank you guys. It is surely not a good idea to use `tr` while we can do it with the pattern substitution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the option of using `awk`, the entire process can be reduced to:

```
awk -F, -v dist=150 '$4<dist {split($1,d,"."); print d[1]":"d[2]":"d[3]","$2}' file
```

Where in the example above, any record with distance (field 4, `$4`) less than the `dist` variable value takes the date field (field 1, `$1`) and `splits()` the field into the array `d` on `"."` where the first 3 elements will be `year`, `mo`, `day` and then simply prints the output of those three elements separated by `":"` (which eliminates the stray `"."` at the end of the field). The time (field 2, `$2`) is output unchanged.

**Example Use/Output**

With your sample data in `file`, you can do:

```
$ awk -F, -v dist=150 '$4<dist {split($1,d,"."); print d[1]":"d[2]":"d[3]","$2}' file
2009:03:10,17:46:17:81
2018:01:05,00:30:37:04
2011:07:11,23:21:53:43
```

Which provides the records in the requested format where the distance is less than `150`. If you call `awk` from within your script you can pass the `150` in from the 1st argument to your script.

You can also accomplish this task by substituting a `':'` for each `'.'` in the first field with `gsub()` and outputting a substring of the first field with `substr()` that drops the last character, e.g.

```
awk -F, -v dist=150 '$4<dist {gsub(/[.]/,":",$1); print substr($1,0,length($1)-1),$2}' file
```

(same output)

While parsing the data is a great exercise for leaning string handling in shell or bash, in practice `awk` will be *Orders of Magnitude* faster than a shell script. Processing a million line file -- the difference in runtime can be seconds with `awk` compared to minutes (or hours) with a shell script.

If this is an exercise to learn string handling in your shell, just put this in your hip pocket for later understanding that `awk` is the real Swiss Army-Knife for text processing. (well worth the effort to learn)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few odd things in your script:

- Why is `fdistance` an array. It is not necessary (and here done wrong) since the file is read line by line.
- What is the `cut` of the line `fdistance=$(cut -d, -f 4)` supposed to cut, what's the input?
- (Note: When invalid parameters, better end the script right away. Added in the example below.)

Here is a working version (apart from the parsing of the date, but that is not what your question was about so I skipped it):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ $# -eq 0 -o $# -gt 1 ]
then
    echo "wrong number of parameters"
    exit 1
fi

input='auto.txt'
while IFS= read -r line
do
    fdistance=$(echo "$line" | awk '{split($0,a,","); print a[4]}')
    if [ "$fdistance" -lt "$1" ]
    then
        echo $line
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Sample output:

```
$ ./test.sh 130
2009.03.10.,17:46:17:81,57,102,57
2011.07.11.,23:21:53:43,310,125,47
$
```